# python ctypes Win32 way window title gets truncted?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I been trying to create Win32 Application by using python (2.7) and ctypes module. Window is created and shown but title of window gets truncated. I got 'M' instead of 'My test window'. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

P.S. Here follows the code and screenshot:

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sys import platform, exit
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, HWND, HANDLE, LPCWSTR, WPARAM, LPARAM, RECT, POINT, MSG

WNDPROCTYPE = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, c_uint, WPARAM, LPARAM)

WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x40000
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = 0xcf0000
WS_CAPTION = 0xc00000

SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
SW_SHOW = 5

CS_HREDRAW = 2
CS_VREDRAW = 1

CW_USEDEFAULT = 0x80000000

WM_DESTROY = 2

WHITE_BRUSH = 0

class WNDCLASSEX(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", c_uint),
                ("style", c_uint),
                ("lpfnWndProc", WNDPROCTYPE),
                ("cbClsExtra", c_int),
                ("cbWndExtra", c_int),
                ("hInstance", HANDLE),
                ("hIcon", HANDLE),
                ("hCursor", HANDLE),
                ("hBrush", HANDLE),
                ("lpszMenuName", LPCWSTR),
                ("lpszClassName", LPCWSTR),
                ("hIconSm", HANDLE)]

def PyWndProcedure(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam):
    if Msg == WM_DESTROY:
        windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
    else:
        return windll.user32.DefWindowProcA(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam)
    return 0

WndProc = WNDPROCTYPE(PyWndProcedure)

hInst = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(0)
print(hInst)

wclassName = u'My Python Win32 Class'

wndClass = WNDCLASSEX()
wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)
wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW
wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc
wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0
wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0
wndClass.hInstance = hInst
wndClass.hIcon = 0
wndClass.hCursor = 0
wndClass.hBrush = windll.gdi32.GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)
wndClass.lpszMenuName = 0
wndClass.lpszClassName = wclassName
wndClass.hIconSm = 0
print(wndClass)

regRes = windll.user32.RegisterClassExW(byref(wndClass))
print(regRes)

wname = u'My test window'

hWnd = windll.user32.CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    wclassName,
    wname,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CAPTION,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300,
    300,
    0,
    0,
    hInst,
    0)
print('hWnd', hWnd)
if not hWnd:
    print('Failed to create window')
    exit(0)

print('ShowWindow', windll.user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW))
print('UpdateWindow', windll.user32.UpdateWindow(hWnd))

msg = MSG()
lpmsg = pointer(msg)

print('Entering message loop')
while windll.user32.GetMessageA(lpmsg, 0, 0, 0) != 0:
    windll.user32.TranslateMessage(lpmsg)
    windll.user32.DispatchMessageA(lpmsg)

print('done.')
```

Comment: Maybe this working example using win32gui.CreateWindow can give you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353883/python3-ctype-createwindowex-simple-example/5355663#5355663

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are creating a Unicode window with `CreateWindowExW` but then calling the ANSI `DefWindowProcA`. You are passing Unicode strings which typically have zero for every other byte since your text is in the ASCII range which explains what you observe.

The solution?  Call `DefWindowProcW` instead.

Actually, a better solution would be to use `win32gui` instead which wraps this up a bit more for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a regular string rather than an unicode string, the text is displayed properly.

wname = 'My test window'

It looks strange to me because you are using the Unicode API (CreateWindowExW). Maybe the root cause is somewhere else.

I hope it helps