# Simple python message box yet customizable on windows?

Tags: python, messagebox

I need to create a simple message box on windows in python, and the message box should be customizable including updating messages/adding(removing) buttons etc.. In order to generate a fairly small-sized standalone executable in the end, I do not want to use big libraries such as wxpython. After a bit of searching, it looks like this is a good start:

```
import ctypes
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
MessageBox(None, 'Hello', 'Window title', 0)
```

But it seems you cannot make buttons disappear in this kind of message boxes, and not able to update the messages as well.

So what choices do I have?

Comment: You want a message box with no button? (like ok, yes/no) ?

Comment: Yeah, that's it and also the text in the msg box should be able to update as well.

Comment: Just give a glance on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388576/python-ctypes-win32-way-window-title-gets-truncted). You can actually create a window with no buttons and a message displayed. It would be hard to think a message box with no button.

Answer (score 0):

The PyMsgBox module does exactly this: https://pymsgbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/