# pywintypes.error: (1407, 'CreateWindowEx'..)

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I try to start coding a MS apllication with python and failed from the start.

My specific question is about this error:

> pywintypes.error: (1407, 'CreateWindowEx', 'Windowclass wasn't found.')

with this code:

```
import ctypes
import win32api
import win32con as con
import win32gui as gui


class Window(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hwnd = gui.CreateWindowEx(0,
                                       "Root",
                                       "Python Window",
                                       con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                       con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                       con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                       con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                       con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       None)
        gui.ShowWindow(self.hwnd, con.SW_SHOWDEFAULT)

Window()
```

Yesterday I readed something about register the window but I cant find it anymore. I think there is the problem. Can someone help me out?

Also if someone reads this question and can give me some general hints, I would be glad.
To descripe my current situation I try to follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/windowing) of MS and try to get an idea of translating C code with python by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53619253/13629335). But Im unable to follow, since the [best documentation of ctypes](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) I found wont help me to use *ctypes only* like in the example.

Comment: Many examples here. Look at example 3 https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/53224/win32gui.CreateWindow

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will take the time to go through some of these.

Comment: FYI, I added a corrected ctypes-only answer to the [linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53619253/13629335) you posted that works with Python 3 32- and 64-bit.

Comment: I'll take a look later this day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates the window class name string is not registered.  `"Root"` must be the name of a registered window class.  See the [CreateWindowsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) documentation:

> lpClassName
>
> Type: **LPCTSTR**
>
> A null-terminated string or a class atom created by a previous call to the [RegisterClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassw) or [RegisterClassEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw) function. The atom must be in the low-order word of *lpClassName*; the high-order word must be zero. If *lpClassName* is a string, it specifies the window class name. The class name can be any name registered with **RegisterClass** or **RegisterClassEx**, provided that the module that registers the class is also the module that creates the window. The class name can also be any of the predefined [system class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes) names.